# Insert element at cursor position in a "contenteditable" div

Tags: javascript, html, insert, contenteditable, text-editor

In my project, I'm trying to wrap inserting elements in a div with "contenteditable=true". The idea is that the user can insert this element at any time in the div, including in the middle of a text, following the cursor position as in `document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset`. Below I show a code example that more or less follows my logic

```js
function insert(text){
  let element = '<span>'+text+'</span>';
  let textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');
  textarea.focus();
  let range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  /*From now on, I should have the code that inserts the "element variable" inside the div in the same position where the user puts the editing cursor, but unfortunately everything I tried gave some kind of error or simply didn't come close*/
}
```

```css
.textarea{
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  height: 200px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
span{
  color: dodgerblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="textarea" id="textarea" contenteditable></div>
<button onclick="insert('additional text')">Insert</button>
```

Comment: You know it's good and admirable that you typed the content of your question in English, and I recognize the effort, but maybe the title could be in English also.

Comment: Yeah, I know! I know how to write in english, but to avoid mistakes I prefer to use google translator and I ended up forgetting to translate the title too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
textarea.textContent = textarea.textContent.substring(0, window.getSelection().baseOffset) +
element +
textarea.textContent.substring(window.getSelection().extentOffset);
```